# How to draw a smooth shape based on 4 points in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, geometry, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm using Sketch to draw a share like the picture below
Basically,the shape has 4 control points,and I want to connect these points into a shape **smoothly**

I tried `UIBezierPath`, but it seems that the API doesn't work for me. E.g, the Right Point shown in the picture, which I need the line to actually *cross* it, while I drag each of these 4 points, I can get a smooth shape, how can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You want something called Catmull-Rom splines. That is a kind of spline where all the control points lie on the curve.

The problem you'll face with Catmull-Rom splines is that with some control points, you can introduce loops or kinks in your curve that you don't want.

I have a project called [RandomBlobs](https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomBlobs.git) on github that demonstrates how to do this.

[Here is a Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMdNUVaU6AQ) showing the output of the app:

(Credit to Erica Sadun, author of the outstanding "[iOS Developers' Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321948106)" series for the technique. And a disclaimer. I was one of the technical reviewers on a couple of her books, but I did so because I really like her writing and wanted to help.)